# How to update entity from new created detached entity

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Let's say I created a new product like this:

```
Product p=new Product(){ Id= 2,Name="some name"};
```

My product variable has never been attached to a data context, how can I attach this entity so that my existing product in the database with Id=2 gets update with the name of my detached product?

Answer (score 0):

I hope something similar would work

```
 Datacontext db = new Datacontext(); // replace with your DataContext
 Product originalProduct = 
         db.Products.Single(p => p.Id == 2); // get product with Id 2

 originalProduct.Name = "SomeName";  // only reset Name prop
 originalProduct = p;                // or you may assign p to originalProduct
 db.SubmitChanges();                 // submit changes to DB
```

Comment: This should definitely work but could be painful to always copy over the properties. In NHibernate they have a construct called Reattach which would let you specify it's an existing object in the DB I'm not sure of L2S has this or not.

Answer (score 0):

A bit easier solution would be to implement the `ICloneable` interface on the entity you would like to work like that. Then, all you need to do is call Clone() into 'original' entity you pulled from the DB.

Example :

```
class Product : ICloneable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Product() { Id=this.Id, Name=this.Name };
    }
}
```

And then all you need to do is :

```
Datacontext db = new Datacontext(); // replace with your DataContext
Product originalProduct = 
        db.Products.Single(p => p.Id == 2); // get product with Id 2

db.originalProduct = p.Clone()
db.SubmitChanges();
```

**Edit :**
I ran into the same problem at work, so far the most elegant solution I found was to build an extension method that recieves the newly created entity, in your case `Product`, and copies it's properties (except for the Identifier) to the entity you pulled from the DataContext.

I copied all the properties via Reflection, this way, if I update the entity, then my extension method will still work.

Hope this helps you too.

If you find a more elegant solution to this problem, I would like to hear :)

Comment: db.originalProduct doesn't seem correct... And when you assign p.Clone() to originalProduct then it is no longer 'attached' to the context, so it won't be persisted.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I didn't fully think it through... I'll check it out and try to fix it. I just ran into the same problem at work, so i need to think of a good solution, and when i do, i'll fix it! :) Thanks!

Comment: If you want to skip using reflection, you could also use the DataContext's MappingSource to copy the values to a new cloned version. This way it'll only copy the properties that pertain specifically to your database.

Comment: Also I think you're looking for DataContext.GetTable<Products>().Attach(original, new) here.

Comment: No prob gillyb! I'll post the code I use as another answer to add on to yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to gillyb's post and the comment I left there. A very easy way for cloning your entity is to do this:

```
Private Function CloneEntity(Of TEntity)(ByVal entity As TEntity) As TEntity

    Dim dataContext As New DataContext()
    Dim entityType As System.Type = GetType(TEntity)

    ' If the purpose of the clone is just to attach it the existing entity to a new
    ' DataContext, you can use IdentityMembers in place of PersistantDataMembers. Setting
    ' only the IdentityMembers is enough to allow for attaching the clone as an "originaL"
    ' entity to the DataContext.
    Dim dataMembers = dataContext.Mapping.GetTable(entityType).RowType.PersistentDataMembers

    Dim clone As TEntity ' Do something here to create an entity of the desired type. 
    Dim boxedClone As Object = clone

    For Each dm In dataMembers

         ' Depending on how your ColumnAttribute is set, you would use StorageAccessor if
         ' the Storage property is set. Otherwise, you would use MemberAccessor instead.
          dm.StorageAccessor.SetBoxedValue(boxedClone, dm.StorageAccessor.GetBoxedValue(entity))
    Next

    Return clone

End Function
```

Then you would just need to do this:

```
Dim dataContext As New DataContext()
dataContext.GetTable(Of Object)().Attach(entityToUpdate, CloneEntity(entityToUpdate))
dataContext.SubmitChanges()
```